# PhpStorm (macOS) + Docker + Xdebug not work

Tags: macos, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I have now switched everything to Docker. The containers are loaded and I have reorganized my projects.

Sample my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    container_name: php2
    image: tamuarchi/yii2-mssql:latest
    volumes:
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      - ./:/app:delegated
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - web2
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal
  db:
    container_name: sql-server-db2
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    volumes:
      - ./mssql-data/backup:/var/opt/mssql/data/backup
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - sql-server-db2
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: 'SUPERP@SSW0RD'
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'

  memcached:
    container_name: memcached2
    image: memcached:latest
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:11211:11211"
volumes:
  my-db:
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

[image: php.ini]
[image: Xdebug]

1) I installed the listener in Chrome

2) I'm launching the containers from PhpStorm

Xdebug is not found or PhpStorm does not stop at the breakpoints. If I run into an error, I also have to restart the container to continue (even if the error is fixed).

Comment: Enable and collect Xdebug log -- it will tell where it tries to connect and what sort of response it gets. That's a starting point, only then you may move to dig deeper into possible reasons.

Comment: Extended:
`XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log`
Where can I find the log file? I was expecting you at /var/log/ in the container.

Comment: Yes, somewhere there (similar location worked fine in my tests in my set up). Do you have SELinux there? Maybe it's not allowing outgoing connections and hence no log created (seen that before; on normal Linux though). Other than that: change location to some another place, verify access permissions. As per your last screenshot you have autostart enabled so Xdebug should be trying to connect for any script and logging that.

Comment: But before that -- check `phpinfo()` output -- do you see correct path to the log there?

Answer (score 0):

What a bummer. In checking the file path... It struck me right away: `xdebug.port = 9005`. Listener set and lets go!

Now the debugger opens at the breakpoint. Unfortunately it does not stop, but there are following errors in the console:

```
16:49   Debug session was finished without being paused
            It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized local and remote projects.
            To figure out the problem check path mappings configuration for 'localhost' server at PHP|Servers or enable Break at first line in PHP scripts option (from Run menu).
```

Comment: So .. configure path mappings: IDE needs to know how to mp your remote `/path/to/project/file.php` to your local actual file. It is done at `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers`. If you not sure how to configure it there, just delete any entries there and let IDE do it for you -- it will show dialog window when it receive the debug connection. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-a-php-debug-server-configuration.html

Comment: The debugger always starts at /web/index.php regardless of where the breakpoint was set.

Comment: Because it's your entry point script, the first code that PHP executes when you hit some URL in your browser. If IDE always stops there then it must be path mapping issue, it cannot figure where else it may stop.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is solved!**

'Break at first line....' was still activated in the settings.